# eth mainnet syncing took 2 weeks or more and still syncing

Tags: fast-sync

I have a node created via AWS but it has been trying to sync for 2 weeks

t2.xlarge running on efs, efs is running on max io and i am using the geth client v.1.9.13

the node state is as below

```
eth.syncing
{
currentBlock: 10676059,
highestBlock: 10676172,
knownStates: 445749597,
pulledStates: 445749204,
startingBlock: 10622772
}
```

anyway to speed up the syncing? i tried to manually add peers as i read that it would help to speedup.
but no matter how many i add the admin.peers.length remains at 16.

my config has set to MaxPeers=50 and set as  fastsync.

Comment: What are your hardware specs? Typically it fails to sync because of HDD.

Comment: The node will not be able to sync if the storage space is not an SSD: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16796#issuecomment-391649278

Comment: i setup a few in parallel

running on the EBS which is a general SSD on AWS 
and also EFS which is like a NFS but the IOPS is comparable to the EBS. 

sync progress EBS is faster.. but still i have another node that is syncing for 5 days it is at 200m knownstates only

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 10676204,
  highestBlock: 10676321,
  knownStates: 210848722,
  pulledStates: 210848721,
  startingBlock: 10655091
}
```